# AutoHotKey: How to access array with counter variable

Tags: autohotkey

```
; Declare the window_title_array
window_title_array%1% = 3270 Display A - A
window_title_array%2% = 3270 Display A - B
window_title_array%3% = 3270 Display A - C
window_title_array%4% = 3270 Display A - D
window_title_array%5% = 3270 Display A - E
window_title_array%6% = 3270 Display A - F

counter := 1

my_string := window_title_array%counter%

MsgBox, %my_string%
```

How to get the string from the array with a counter variable? I tried to do `counter = 1` and `counter := 1`. Both of them failed to access the array. I am not sure where is the mistake. Thank you!

PS: The version I have is quite outdated - Version 1.0.47.06

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's in how you're creating your array. By putting percent signs around your array indexes, you're actually saying that you want to use the first file-level input parameter (in the case of using %1%).  This is most likely blank, so what it ends up looking for is a variable named "window_title_array"

Take out the percents. You should use this:

```
window_title_array1 = 3270 Display A - A
window_title_array2 = 3270 Display A - B
window_title_array3 = 3270 Display A - C
window_title_array4 = 3270 Display A - D
window_title_array5 = 3270 Display A - E
window_title_array6 = 3270 Display A - F
```

And not this:

```
window_title_array%1% = 3270 Display A - A
window_title_array%2% = 3270 Display A - B
window_title_array%3% = 3270 Display A - C
window_title_array%4% = 3270 Display A - D
window_title_array%5% = 3270 Display A - E
window_title_array%6% = 3270 Display A - F
```

And then if you want to reference something with a counter variable, ... (looking at your code)...  you would do it exactly like you are.

And note that this is not a native array in AHK.  But if you have an older version you may not be able to use native arrays.  This is how arrays were done for a long time in AHK.

Furthermore, another way I deal with this is by creating a "built-in" counter/length variable and use that to dynamically number my arrays.  Then that can easily be referenced in array loops etc.  And notice no hand-coding of array indexes, which means you can add more or insert them without having to renumber anything.  I'm often doing arrays of structures, and below is a simple example...

```
myArr0 = 0  ; At the end, this will hold the count of the array

myArr0++
myArr%myArr0%_firstName = John
myArr%myArr0%_lastName = Smith

myArr0++
myArr%myArr0%_firstName = Bill
myArr%myArr0%_lastName = Jones

myNames = 
; assemble a list of names, a simple example
loop, %myArr0%
{
myNames := myNames . myArr%a_index%_firstName . ", "
}
```

And I use the <array name>0 syntax for the counter because that's the same syntax as outputted by the stringsplit command.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in `counter` variable, both of your versions will work fine but I suggest you to always use only `:=` in AutoHotkey. You can use expression with `:=` and if you need to assign text to variable just enclose text with `""` like  this `a := "Some text here"`. But to assign to the variable the result of expression dont use `""`, like this `a:= 1+1`. Try to not use `=` for assignment in AutoHotkey. 
Look in comments in my code and notes below my code for explanation. Here is working code:

```
window_title_array := [] ; We create array here

; we are adding items to array.
window_title_array[1] := "3270 Display A - A"
window_title_array[2] := "3270 Display A - B"
window_title_array[3] := "3270 Display A - C"
window_title_array[4] := "3270 Display A - D"
window_title_array[5] := "3270 Display A - E"
window_title_array[6] := "3270 Display A - F"

counter := 1

my_string := window_title_array[counter] ; here we need [] to indicate that we are using array cell and variable incide it does not needs to be enclosed in %%

MsgBox, %my_string%
```

Here you can get more infor about arrays and AutoHotkey http://ahkscript.org/docs/Objects.htm#Usage 
Keep in mind that all arrays in AutoHotkey are objects.
also you can declare array and add values in one string. More about it in link that a gave you above.

*Also, always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*

Comment: Is it because of the version of the AHK I have? The code you provided does not print the title of the window...

Comment: @George I have checked the codeI gave you and works fine with the current uptodate version of AutoHotkey form ahkscript.org .

Comment: @George It prints `3270 Display A - A` in message box.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a really old version... Version 1.0.47.06.

Comment: @George Download new version from here http://ahkscript.org/download/ahk-install.exe

Comment: it is a company computer :(