# accessing array content whithin for loop - Auto Hot Key AHK

Tags: arrays, autohotkey

I am trying to extract the content of an array member at index i into a variable and then append it to a file.
How do I do that ?
Here is what I tried but it will not take the content of cgi[i]

```
firstrun(){
GuiControlGet, cgiDelay,,_cgiDelay
returnCode:=[]
for i in cgi {
    msg := "http://" ip "/Nexus.cgi?session=" session "&action=" firstRunCgi[i] "&tokenoverride=1"
    sendToHttp(msg)
    getRespond()
    returnCode[i]:=parseReturnCode()
    if (returnCode[i] !=0){
        addTextToGui("Setting 1st run Fail #: " i "`terrorCode: " returnCode[i] "`t"firstRunCgi[i])
        txt = `ncgi[i],skipped
        FileAppend, %txt%, cgiLog.txt
        cgi[i] :=""
        }
    else{
    ;   addTextToGui("Setting 1st run OK #: " i "`terrorCode: " returnCode[i] "`t"firstRunCgi[i])
    }
    Sleep (cgiDelay)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now sure why and how but this fixed it:

```
            txt := "`n" cgi[i] ",skipped"
        FileAppend, %txt%, cgiLog.csv
```

See here: [AutoHotKey: How to access array with counter variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772799/autohotkey-how-to-access-array-with-counter-variable)

Answer (score 0):

In your Example you posted: `For i in cgi` the variable `i` contains your Key/Index, so you can access a Value in cgi Array with the Key/Index by: `value := cgi[i]`

Alternatatively you can declare two variables to hold both your Key/Index and Value directly in your For loop like so:

```
cgi := ["Hello", "World"]
For i, v in cgi ; Notice the comma
     MsgBox % "This is the Key/Index: " i 
            . "`nThis is the Value from the For loop: " v
            . "`nThis Value was accessed using Key/Index: " cgi[i]
```